# How to make Python produce "LF" only in a Text file

Tags: python, unix, text, ascii, bytecode

I am creating a file using Python, the upload it to a unix server to be executed by a program in EM. But I found the file will only be accepted if there is "LF" only. In the Python program, if I use '\n' in the file, it produces 'CRLF', if I use '\r' in the file, it produces 'CR'. Although I can replace 'CR' with 'LF' in notepad++ before I upload it, it means an extra step which is not easy to be automated.
Is there anyway to let the Python write 'LF' only into the file, no 'CRLF', or 'CR'.

Comment: I can't repro this. If you are on Windows, probably mention this.

Comment: See the given duplicate, using the `newline=` parameter of `print`

Comment: Yes, I am on windows. I cannot access unix. The file loading is by a tool.